# Understanding Backbone.js event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

So here is my view:

```
$(function() {
var ImageManipulation = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $('body'),
    tagName: "img",

    events: {
        'mouseover img': 'fullsize',
        'click img#current': 'shrink'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'fullsize', 'shrink');

        //var message = this.fullsize;
        //message.bind("test", this.fullsize);
    },
    render: function() {

    },
    fullsize: function() {
        console.log("in fullsize function");
        console.log(this.el);
        $('.drop-shadow').click(function() {
            console.log(this.id);
            if (this.id != 'current') {
                $('.individual').fadeIn();
                $(this).css('position', 'absolute');
                $(this).css('z-index', '999');
                $(this).animate({
                    top: '10px',
                    height: '432px',
                }, 500, function() {
                    this.id = "current";
                    console.log("animation complete");
                    return true;
                });
            };
        });
    },
    shrink: function() {
        $('.individual').fadeOut();
        $('#current').animate({
            height: '150px',
        }, 500, function() {
            this.id = "";
            $(this).css('position', 'relative');
            $(this).css('z-index', '1');
            console.log("animation complete");
            return true;
        });
    }
});
var startImages = new ImageManipulation();
});
```

What I don't understand is how to change the el to make 'this' take over the click function I have in full-size.  I would much rather have the click jQuery function removed and have the mouseover function be another click, but I cant seem to figure out how to assign 'this' to the particular image that is being clicked. I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: I think you might have to use serialise `http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-extend` also the `el: 'body'` not `$('body')` it's on one of the examples so it probably expects it to be a string rather than an object

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Backbone's event handler assumes that you want to know about the object (both its code, and its DOM representation, the `View.el` object) for every event, and that the event is intended to change some aspect of the view and/or model. The actual target of the click is something you're assumed to know, or assumed to be able to derive.

Derivation is rather simple:

```
fullsize: function(ev) {
    target = $(ev.currentTarget);
```

And replace all your `this.` references within your call to `target.`.  `this.` will continue to refer to the `View` instance.  In your inner function, the anonymous one assigned to `.drop-shadow`, `this.` will refer to the object that was just clicked on.  If you want access to the surrounding context, use the closure forwarding idiom:

```
fullsize: function(ev) {
    var target = ev.currentTarget;
    var self = this;
    $('.drop-shadow').click(function(inner_ev) {
        console.log(this.id);  // the same as inner_ev.currentTarget
        console.log(self.cid); // the containing view's CID
```

Comment: Fantastic Explanation Elf! My code looks so much more concise now, and I understand more about Backbone!

Comment: A common alternative is to use the `_.bind()` method (provided by backbone's dependency, underscore.js) to bind the inner function to `this` (the View object) and use the `ev.currentTarget`, instead of the `self/this` trick.