# Get the id of the button, from a range of unique dynamic buttons in backbone

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, backbone-events

i have a list of buttons while are displayed by Handlebars template

```
<button class="providesolution" id="btn{{issue_id}}" ><small>Post</small></button>
```

Here the id is unique for all the buttons that i have.

On the Backbone View for the event

```
 events: {
    'click .providesolution': 'providesolution',
         },


 providesolution: function(){

    /* how to get the id of the button here when clicked   */

       }
```

i have tried in many ways to get id but it shows undefined.
Could anyone help me on this?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

backbone passes the event as the first argument to the event handler and you can get the element that caused the event from the event data structure like this:

```
providesolution: function(e) {

    /* how to get the id of the button here when clicked   */
    var id = e.currentTarget.id;
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847182/understanding-backbone-js-event-handler) and [here](http://danielarandaochoa.com/backboneexamples/blog/2012/02/28/handling-the-click-event-with-backbone/) for other examples.

Unlike in plain Javascript event handlers and with jQuery event handlers, the value of `this` is your view, not the element that caused the event, but you can get that element from the event structure.